# Connection to Elasticsearch 5.x is taking to long. NEST 5.0 rc

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am new in Elasticsearch and I have problems with the connection to the elasticsearch server.

I am using Elasticsearch 5.0.1, and I am running my code under .NET 4.5.2.
I am using NEST 5.0 rc lib.

I also installed Kibana and x-pack in my pc.

My code to connect to elasticsearch:

```
var nodes = new Uri[] { new Uri("http://localhost:9200") };
var pool = new StaticConnectionPool(nodes);
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool).DefaultIndex("visitor_index");            
var client =  ElasticClient(settings);
```

My Search code:

```
var result = client.Search<VisitorTest>(s => s.Index("visitor_index")
    .Query(q => q.Match(mq => mq.Field(f => f.Name).Query("Visitor 1"))));
```

Basically the problem that I am having is that each time I create a new ElasticClient it take between 40-80 milliseconds to establish the connection.
I created a UT for this in which I am creating a connection and running the search query twice, and then I am creating a second connection in the same test and run again the search query two times.
The result is that the first query after the connection takes between 40-80 millisecond and the second query with the same connection take 2 milliseconds that is what I expect.

I tried changing the connection string to use a domain (added the domain to my local host file). I also tried removing xpack security so I do not need to authenticate.

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

But I always get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few observations

1. A single instance of `ConnectionSettings` should be reused for the lifetime of the application. `ConnectionSettings` makes heavy use of caching so should be reused.
2. `ElasticClient` is thread-safe. A single instance can be safely used for the lifetime of an application
3. Unless you have a collection of nodes, I would recommend using `SingleNodeConnectionPool` instead of `StaticConnectionPool`. The latter has logic to round-robin over nodes which is unneeded for a single node.
4. The client takes advantage of connection pooling within the .NET framework; you can adjust `KeepAlive` behaviour on `ConnectionSettings` with `EnableTcpKeepAlive()`
5. If you have a web proxy configured on your machine, you could have a look at disabling automatic proxy detection with `.DisableAutomaticProxyDetection()` on `ConnectionSettings`.

Comment: Definitely the problem was the 'ConnectionSettings'. Once I started using a single instance of that the connection time (for new clients) reduced to 5 milliseconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my few coins here.

Had exactly same issue with 40 ms requests. However from Kibana dev tools it was taking 1 ms.

Fixed by tweaking two things:

**Ninject part:**

```
kernel.Bind<IEsClientProvider>().To<EsClientProvider>().InSingletonScope().WithConstructorArgument("indexName", "items");
```

And in **client provider:**

```
public ElasticClient GetClient()
    {
        if (this.client == null)
        {
            settings = new ConnectionSettings(nodeUri).DefaultIndex(indexName);
            this.client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        }

        return client;
    }
```